# looking for <>VBA <>Copy<> paste<>specific data

Tags: excel, vba, matching

I’m trying to create a Macro to look up matching ID and then paste a returned Value Approved in a different cell but the same row
I went pretty well but then the problem that I can’t fix is : the data gets copied in the first cells of the columns. Not in the same cells that are matching the rows where the ID are
Please help me with that code.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Order_Number As String
Dim Finalrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders")

sh.Unprotect "2021"

Sheets("orders").Range("L3:L900000").ClearContents

Order_Number = Me.ComboBox1.Value
Finalrow = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To Finalrow
   If Order_Number = Cells(i, 11) Then
          sh.Range("AA3:AA4" & Finalrow).Copy
          sh.Range("L3" & Finalrow).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
   End If
Next i
Range("L3").Select
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Range.Find` instead of a loop

Comment: You are using `FinalRow` as the row to copy. Is this right? This is essentially static. You are also pasting in the `FinalRow` (and then trying to go up from there). This doesn't seem correct. The variable `i` indicates the row you are currently on. So you may want to copy from row `i` and paste to row `i` (i.e. swap the variables you have). Guessing though. You have not really explained what should be copied from where and to where